# Listing the filtered items in excel

Tags: excel

Excel, Windows 10

Say I built a pivot table in excel. The issue I have is that when I select multiple items in the pivot table filter, I can only see `(Multiple Items)` in the cell pertaining to the pivot table filter.

--> I would like to be able to have a cell that would contain a list of all the items that were selected in that filter for summary purpose.

Is there a way to do that in excel?

Comment: You need `TEXTJOIN()` function which is available in Excel 2019 and later versions.

Comment: Thanks but that would give me only the value that is showing in the cell pertaining to the filter value.  I meant that I would want to obtain each individual actual values that are selected in the filter.

Comment: You could uses slicers - there you are able to see the selected values. But this is only visual.

Comment: Found out a complete solution explained on: 
 https://youtu.be/RplIrd5G5_o: